# Getting error in printing the dictionary values to html

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I want to print to get the details of different cities weather and I had written the code as below. While retrieving the data, I am not able to fetch the data to HTML.

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
import urllib.request
import json
import requests

def display(request):
    city=['vijayawada','guntur','tenali','rajahmundry','amaravathi']
    for i in city:
        source = urllib.request.urlopen(
            'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + i + '&units=metric&appid=5980455dc827c861d5ac4125c3673b43').read()
        list_of_data = json.loads(source)

        data = {
            "country_code": str(list_of_data['sys']['country']),
            "coordinate": str(list_of_data['coord']['lon']) + ', '
                          + str(list_of_data['coord']['lat']),

            "temp": str(list_of_data['main']['temp']) + ' °C',
            "pressure": str(list_of_data['main']['pressure']),
            "humidity": str(list_of_data['main']['humidity']),
            'main': str(list_of_data['weather'][0]['main']),
            'description': str(list_of_data['weather'][0]['description']),
            'icon': list_of_data['weather'][0]['icon'],
        }
        print(data)
    return render(request, "display.html",data)
```

`display.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>API Display</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Weather details</h1>
    <form>
{% for i in data %}
{{ country_code }}
{{ temp }}
{{ i }}
{% endfor %}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to print the values of the dictionary to html but not getting printed. The values are printing correctly in the console which means the for loop in `views.py` is working correctly.

Please tell me where I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make a function that handles the request for each city:

```
def get_city_weather(city_name):
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(
            'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city_name + '&units=metric&appid=5980455dc827c861d5ac4125c3673b43').read()
    list_of_data = json.loads(source)

    return {
        "country_code": str(list_of_data['sys']['country']),
        "coordinate": str(list_of_data['coord']['lon']) + ', '
                      + str(list_of_data['coord']['lat']),

        "temp": str(list_of_data['main']['temp']) + ' °C',
        "pressure": str(list_of_data['main']['pressure']),
        "humidity": str(list_of_data['main']['humidity']),
        'main': str(list_of_data['weather'][0]['main']),
        'description': str(list_of_data['weather'][0]['description']),
        'icon': list_of_data['weather'][0]['icon'],
    }
```

Then use dict comprehension to compile the `data` dict to send to the template:

```
def display(request):
    cities=['vijayawada','guntur','tenali','rajahmundry','amaravathi']
    
    data = {city_name: get_city_weather(city_name) for city_name in cities}

    return render(request, "display.html", data)
```

At this point `data` is a dictionary who's key is the city name and who's value is the dictionary returned by `get_city_weather`, so it looks like (abbreviated):

```
{'vijayawada': 
    {'country_code': 'ABC'
    # ...
    }
# ...
}
```

Then in the template you could loop through this like:

```
{% for city_name, city_weather in data.items %}
The temperature in {{city_name}} is {{city_weather.temp}}
 and the air pressure is {{city_weather.pressure}}.
{% endfor %}
```

Or if you don't want to specify the keys like `temp` and `pressure`, you could do:

```
{% for city_name, city_weather in data.items %}
<p>Weather data for {{city_name}}:</p>

<ul>
{% for k,v in city_weather.items %}
  <li>{{k}}: {{v}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<hr />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Consider explaining what's the issue, not simply provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**, [django template system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/) recognizes dict variable just like Python itself does.
So, if we try to convert your template code back to Python code, we would get something like this:

```
for i in data:
  print(country_code)
  print(temp)
  print(i)
```

Now, ask yourself: *will it work?*
Obviously, it's not.

So, how exactly in Python you would loop and access dict values?
You can do it like this:

```
for i in data:
  print(i)
```

Or with `k,v` loop variables (better way):

```
for k, v in enumerate(data):
  print(f"key: {k}, value: {v}")
```

But, in your template code, you are trying to access certain values with the key (`country_code` etc).
In this case, you probably don't even need to use the for-loop.
And your `display.html` file can be rewritten like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>API Display</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Weather details</h1>
    <form>
{{ data.country_code }}
{{ data.temp }}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, as I can see your view retrieves this `data` for each given city.
Thought you only pass the last one to your template.
In order to fix this, you must rewrite your view code.

I guess you could add a new variable called `collected_data` and then at the end of every data retrieve loop just append `data` to this new variable.
After that, you could just pass the `collected_data` to the template.
And then loop through it within the template.

But I exactly don't know how your template should look like, so I leave it to you.
I've tried to explain what's the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are overwriting your data dictionary. It's being passed only as one object, it should render something if you try `{{data}}` or `{{data.country_code}}`, `{{data.temp}}`...

One way to solve this, is to have a nested dictionary with the data of every city:

views.py

```
def loop_dict(request):
    cities=['vijayawada','guntur','tenali','rajahmundry','amaravathi']
    data = {}
    for city in cities:
        source = urllib.request.urlopen(
            'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&units=metric&appid=5980455dc827c861d5ac4125c3673b43').read()
        list_of_data = json.loads(source)

        data[city] = {
            "country_code": str(list_of_data['sys']['country']),
            "coordinates": {
                'latitude':  str(list_of_data['coord']['lat']),
                'longitude': str(list_of_data['coord']['lon'])
            },
            "temp": str(list_of_data['main']['temp']) + ' °C',
            "pressure": str(list_of_data['main']['pressure']),
            "humidity": str(list_of_data['main']['humidity']),
            'main': str(list_of_data['weather'][0]['main']),
            'description': str(list_of_data['weather'][0]['description']),
            'icon': list_of_data['weather'][0]['icon'],
        }
    context = {'data': data}

    return render(request, 'loop_dict.html', context)
```

loop_dict.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for key, obj in data.items %}
        <h2>City: {{key}}</h2><br>
        <p>Country Code: {{obj.country_code}}</p><br>
        <p>Latitude: {{obj.coordinates.latitude}}</p><br>
        <p>Longitude: {{obj.coordinates.longitude}}</p><br>
        <p>Temp: {{obj.temp}}</p><br>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```